# Define AuthenticationProviders per RequestMatchers (Spring Security 6)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

we need to support both SAML authentiction as well as HTTP basic authentication  in one of our apps. We configured an AuthenticationProvider for each of the configurations, and use different roles, too. Since the HTTP basic users only have (role-based) access to a particular subset of the api, I'd like to split authentication providers to match that situation, since there is no need to check both providers. Using Spring Security 5, documentation recommends doing something like:

```kotlin
    ...
    httpSecurity.antMatchers("/basic-path/**")
        .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_BASIC")
        .and()
        .authenticationManager(basicAuthManager)
        .antMatchers("/other-path/**")
        .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_SAML")
        .and()
        .authenticationManager(samlAuthManager)
    ...
```

In Spring Security 6 `and()` is deprecated, and we don't have a similar way to specify an `authenticationManager()`. At the moment, we define:

```kotlin
    ...
    httpSecurity.authenticationManager(basicAuthManager)
        .authorizeHttpRequests { authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
            authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/basic-path/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_BASIC")
                ...
        }
    httpSecurity.authenticationManager(samlAuthManager)
        .authorizeHttpRequests { authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
            authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/other-path/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_SAML")
                ...
        }
    ...

    // this enables http basic globally on all paths
    httpSecurity.httpBasic {}

    // enable saml, also gobally
    httpSecurity.saml2Login { saml2LoginConfigurer ->
        saml2LoginConfigurer
            .authenticationManager(ProviderManager(samlAuthenticationProvider()))
         ...
    }
```

I could not yet find a way to specify which authenticationManager/authenticationProvider to use for which path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it. The main idea here is to use two seperate filters, but both need to be configured to only work for a spefific subset of all api paths. So Spring needs to know, if any of the filters applies to a specific path before checking the `requestMatcher()`-settings to determin whether to accept or decline a request. This can be achieved using `securityMatcher()` as depmonstrated in the following example:

```kotlin
class SecurityConfig {
    ...

    @Bean
    fun samlSecurityFilterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity,
        registrations: RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository
    ): SecurityFilterChain {
        // all "normal" users use SAML and paths matching the securityMatcher here 
        http.securityMatcher("/other-path/**")
            .authenticationManager(samlAuthManager)
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                    .requestMatchers("/other-path/path1/**")
                    .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_SAML_1")
                    .requestMatchers("/other-path/path2/**")
                    .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_SAML_2")
                
                    ...
            }
        
            ...

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun basicSecurityFilterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity
    ): SecurityFilterChain {
        // technical users use basic auth and the paths matching this securityMatcher
        http.securityMatcher("/basic-path/**")
            .authenticationManager(basicAuthManager)
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry ->
                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
                    .requestMatchers("/basic-path/path1/**")
                    .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_BASIC_1")
                    .requestMatchers("/basic-path/path2/**")
                    .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_BASIC_2")
                
                    ...
            }

        http.httpBasic(withDefaults())
        
            ...

        return http.build()
    }

    ...
}
```